# How can i use double buffering with graphics.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, header, bgi

So i have never worked with double buffering before but i know that the basic idea is to draw an invisible layer for the next frame and leaving the old frame on until the new one is done and then replacing them. But how can i accomplish this?
Im rather new to the whole graphics thing and my teacher said that i need to use graphics.h for now. So im kinda stuck on it.
I dont think my code matters in this case so i wont post it.
Really all im trying to accomplish is a flickerless refresh ;D
Please give me a step by step explanation ;D
All the explanation on google were very vague only describing how it works rather than how to do it with the given commands.
Im using win10 and visual studio 2015 community.

EDIT: Im using the package from http://winbgim.codecutter.org/ .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not going to get very far trying to use (legacy) `graphics.h` on a modern system without using something like WinBGI.

Comment: Yes im using that too. Its included in that zip that you get for graphics.h . Im gonna include it in the post. Thanks!

Comment: So your teacher is _forcing_ you to use `graphics.h`? What a dick biting asshat!

Comment: well lets not say forcing. We are gonna hold a small game competition in our class and we gotta do it using graphics.h . So its kinda forcing but because we are in 1st grade most of us wont understand opengl.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. Simply use setactivepage() and setvisualpage().